# Navigation stops after 15 min in background skobbler

Tags: ios, skmaps

I am using Skobbler sdk in my application for navigation. I need to continuously send data of navigation to other device. But the navigation in background works for only 15 minutes after that it stops navigating in background. I have also tried enabling the following key value pairs in plist :
Required Background modes- 
1. App registers for location updates
2. App downloads content from the network

Please suggest some help.

Comment: Inside SDKTools there is an example of how to make sure that navigation works in the background: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/iosTools#sec07. Could it be that after 15 minutes you've arrived at your destination? (stopping the navigation)

Answer (score 1):

Please test this in a real situation, like actually driving while using the app with navigation type being SKNavigationTypeReal.

Background apps are suspended after some time and only activated when they actually receive GPS location updates. Your app will never resume if the device is not actually moving.

This is an optimization done by Apple to improve battery life. 
Some more info about background modes: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

The next release will include an API to disable this behavior.